# MyBatisでPostgreSQLのARRAY型が取得できない

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

MyBatisでARAAY型の値が取得できません。
Tomcatを起動した時点で、以下のようなエラーが発生してしまいます。

[MyBatisのリファレンス](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/ja/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps)の「サポートされている JDBC データ型」には
ARRAYの記載があるので対応しているとは思うのですが。
ご知識のある方、お教示お願いいたします。

【Tomcat起動時エラー】

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receiveMapper' defined in file [D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.14\wtpwebapps\MamaFriends\WEB-INF\classes\com\hatak\mamafriends\mapper\logic\receive\ReceiveMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Result Maps collection already contains value for com.hatak.mamafriends.mapper.logic.receive.ReceiveMapper.messagesResultMap
（以下略）
```

【XML】

```
<resultMap id="messagesBirthdayResultMap"  type="getMessagesBirthdayEntity">
    <id     property="uid"         column="uid"        jdbcType="VARCHAR" />
    <result property="birthdays"   column="birthdays"  jdbcType="ARRAY" />
</resultMap>

<select id="getMessagesBirthday" parameterType="GetMessagesBirthdayEntity" resultMap="messagesBirthdayResultMap">
    SELECT
        m.id AS uid
        ,ARRAY(SELECT c.birthday FROM children c WHERE m.from_uid = c.uid) AS birthdays
    FROM messages m
    ORDER BY m.created DESC
    OFFSET #{offset}
    LIMIT #{limit}
    ;
</select>
```

【Entity】

```
public class GetMessagesBirthdayEntity {

    private String uid = "";
    private Date[] birthdays = null;

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public Date[] getBirthdays() {
        return birthdays;
    }

    public void setBirthdays(Date[] birthdays) {
        this.birthdays = birthdays;
    }
}
```

【ミドルウェアバージョン】
MyBatis：3.2.8
PosrgreSQL：9.5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyBatis で JDBC ↔ Java の型変換を行うのは TypeHandler です。
TypeHandler は基本的に `javaType` と `jdbcType` の組み合わせで登録および検索されますが、`ARRAY` の変換を行う ArrayTypeHandler はデフォルトだと `java.lang.Object` と `ARRAY` の組み合わせに対してのみ登録されているようです。

なので、以下のいずれかの方法で `birthdays` のマッピングに ArrayTypeHandler が使われるように指示する必要があります。

1. MyBatis の設定ファイルで `java.util.Date[]` と `ARRAY` の組み合わせに対して ArrayTypeHandler を登録する（`date[]` はエイリアス）。

   ```xml
   <typeHandlers>
     <typeHandler handler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler"
       javaType="date[]" jdbcType="ARRAY" />
   </typeHandlers>
   ```
2. `result` 要素に対して `typeHandler` を明示的に指定する。

   ```xml
   <result property="birthdays" column="birthdays"
     typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ArrayTypeHandler" />
   ```

Comment: 的確なご回答ありがとうございます。